# Make a copy of a Google Drive Template by URL

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to make a copy of a Google Drive Document Template and then open it in a new browser tab for editing.

The best way I know to do this is simply use the Document's template URL...

https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.com/document/d/ABC9DWlLOn7uXYyJB1RqzkmHl5FZFMNmMsF-Y8YAz-uY/copy?token=n4hj23gk54.b325h.kAfj-N7rU-Pj1OzMzQmQvA

Basically I would put that URL in an anchor tag with target="_blank" and clicking that link would copy the template to MY Google Drive and then open it in a new tab.

My plan doesn't work, because the URL requires a token parameter - I assume that's the destination for the document...  The above example works, but only because I know the token - I can figure out my token easy enough, but how can I get another user's token on the fly to compose the URL to execute the URL command I desire?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older link, but for those who find it in the future...  you can do this with a preview link that presents a user with the option to use the template.  Use this:

```
https://drive.google.com/a/(your domain)/previewtemplate?id=(id copied from template file)&mode=domain
```

or even without the a/domain:

```
https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=(id copied from template file)&mode=domain
```

*BTW, the file must be a template and sharing set appropriately*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no facility in the Drive SDK for generating these template URLs.

It is a reasonable (but rare) feature request that we will investigate, and I will get back on this post if there are any updates.

Comment: Any other advice for accomplishing a one click template reproduction?

Comment: Sorry, not that I know of, but I am no expert in this.